# Angular material form-field class "mat-form-field-outline" cannot be modified with a css selector

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I am attempting to slightly change look of mat-form-field the "outline" look, precisely removing it's border-radius on the border line.

When I add at global stylesheet following code attempting to change properties

```
.mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline-start {
  border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
}

.mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline-end {
  border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
}
```

I observe it has no effect.
I would expect it to work because

```
.mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline-start {
  display: none;
}

.mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline-end {
  display: none;
}
```

does successfully removes the outlines so no problem with the selector matching.

I am not able to change properties but I can add new one's.

How is the correct approach? Should I submit and issue over angular components github tracker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use ::ng-deep since it's a different component.

```
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline-start {
  border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
}
```

Docs say it's deprecated, but there is no alternative (and everyone is using it) so you should be fine.

If you want to change in one component only make sure to add `:host` before

Comment: I am aware of ::ng-deep, however on a component level it behaves the same. I can hide it or add new properties but it wont change them.

Comment: Try with `!important`. If it works it means it prefers default css over yours. I did something similar a few months back but, don't have access to repo any more.

Comment: Thank you very much, I never thought I would need such a dinosaur css thing. It works now.

Comment: Further clarification - `::ng-deep` is needed only for components css not necessary to use it in global `style.scss`. The `!important` was indeed important to make it work.